# Помогите, что это за функция такая?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, сетевое-программирование, задание-на-собеседовании

Дано число, которое состоит только из цифр 6 и 9.

Цифры можно "вращать" - заменять 6 на 9 или 9 на 6.

Написать функцию, которая находит максимальное число, которое можно получить из исходного числа путем "вращения" максимум одной цифры.

Реализовать код в виде изолированной функции rot(num).

Пример

Вход: num=9669

Результат: 9969

Comment: Очевидно, что нужно перевернуть самую левую шестёрку. Именно она имеет наибольший "вес".

Comment: Да, уж, где вы берете такие "задачки"? Очевидно, что девятки "вращать" совсем не надо, вас просто разводят

Answer (score 3):

Вот куда более простой способ:

```
def rot(num):
    num = str(num)
    num = num.replace('6', '9', 1)
    return int(num)

print(rot(9669))
```

`replace('6', '9', 1)` - функция, которая меняет 6 на 9 в строке ровно 1 раз. Если не указать 1 в конце, то будут заменены все 6 в строке, а так "переворачивается" только первая 6

Comment: Даст неверный результат на числе, в котором нет шестёрок.

Comment: @Akina, с чего бы? В числе есть только цифры 6 и 9. Если нет 6, то число 9999 и тп и оно уже наибольшее в этом случае

Comment: Ну если понимать, что можно или одну цифирь "повернуть", или ни одной - то тогда да.

Comment: @Akina, тут был другой ответ(не знаю зачем автор удалил его). И там автор вопроса написала пример: 9999, а возвращает 9999. Так что да. У нас есть возможность ни одной цифры не поворачивать. Главное получить наибольшее число

Answer (score 1):

Строчный метод:

```
replace(old_value, new_value, count)
```

меняет первую шестерку на девятку. Замена происходит только один раз, т.к. `count = 1`:

```
def rot(num):
    return int(str(num).replace("6","9", 1)))
rot(9669)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Только на выходе у вас будет строка, а в задаче вроде бы и на входе и на выходе число.

Comment: Сейчас внесу изменения, не заметил

Comment: @Bitchdragon, ответ, фактически, тотже что и у меня + девушка не сможет отметить ответ галочкой, т.к. это был незарегистрированный аккаунт

Comment: И, кстати, судя по вопросу, человек плохо знает питон, потому ваш ответ, фактически, куда сложнее и непонятнее для такого человека

Comment: Да просто у меня привычка еще с CodeWars: Когда функцию вижу, то автоматически пытаюсь ее сводить к 1 строке))